# Euclid's Algorithm Function parameters

Tags: c++, algorithm, parameters

I've written a program for class where I need to recursively evaluate the extended euclid's algorithm for a and b, returning G, the greatest common divisor, as well as s and t from as+bt=gcd(a,b).  I'm fairly certain I have the function written correctly but I am having issues with values being passed to and from the function.  I haven't coded in a while and have only written pseudocode recently so I'm a little rusty.

For example, I have written when b=0, return (a, 1, 0), but when I input b as 0 I get returned  (0, 0, 0) and cannot figure out why this is happening.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ExtGCD (int a, int b)
{
    int g, s, t, g1, s1, t1;
    if (b == 0) {
        return (a, 1, 0);
    }
    (g1, s1, t1) = ExtGCD(b, a%b);
    g = g1;
    s = s1;
    t = s1 - ((a/b)*t1);
    return (g, s, t);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a,b, g2, s2, t2, temp;
    cout << "Please input a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please input b: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b > a) {
        temp = a; a = b; b = temp;
    }
    (g2, s2, t2) = ExtGCD (a, b);
    cout << "G = "<< g2 << ", S = " << s2 << ", T = " << t2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm almost positive it's going to be something related to the comma operator, but I don't know enough to give a full answer just yet.

Comment: `return (g, s, t);` -- What is this supposed to mean?  This is not Python!

Comment: print your `a` and `b`. If you type "0", that's actually ascii code 48. Find out what `a` and `b` are when you type them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (g, s, t);
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It's not possible to return multiple values from a function like that. Look up the comma operator if you want an explanation of what that code does.

There's a few different ways you could handle this. Perhaps the simplest is to return your values via references passed to the function. Like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ExtGCD (int a, int b, int& g, int& s, int& t)
{
    int g1, s1, t1;
    if (b == 0) {
        g = a;
        s = 1;
        t = 0;
        return;
    }
    ExtGCD(b, a%b, g1, s1, t1);
    g = g1;
    s = s1;
    t = s1 - ((a/b)*t1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a,b, g2, s2, t2, temp;
    cout << "Please input a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please input b: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b > a) {
        temp = a; a = b; b = temp;
    }
    ExtGCD (a, b, g2, s2, t2);
    cout << "G = "<< g2 << ", S = " << s2 << ", T = " << t2;
    return 0;
}
```

In this code `g`, `s` and `t` are references, which means assignments to them change the values of the variables bound to the references when the function is called.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'd completely forgotten about references and changing variables from inside functions.

Answer (score 9):

C++11 introduces tuples, which allow you to write your code like this, with minimal modifications:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;
std::tuple<int, int, int> ExtGCD (int a, int b)
{
    int g, s, t, g1, s1, t1;
    if (b == 0) {
        return std::make_tuple(a, 1, 0);
    }
    std::tie(g1, s1, t1) = ExtGCD(b, a%b);
    g = g1;
    s = s1;
    t = s1 - ((a/b)*t1);
    return std::make_tuple(g, s, t);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a,b, g2, s2, t2, temp;
    cout << "Please input a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please input b: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b > a) {
        temp = a; a = b; b = temp;
    }
    std::tie(g2, s2, t2) = ExtGCD (a, b);
    cout << "G = "<< g2 << ", S = " << s2 << ", T = " << t2;
    return 0;
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple.

On a related note, you can also replace

```
if (b > a) {
    temp = a; a = b; b = temp;
}
```

by

```
if (b > a)
    std::swap(a, b);
```

or even by

```
std::tie(b, a) = std::minmax({a, b});
```

The C++ standard library provides many algorithmic facilities that should be learned to enjoy C++ to its full potential.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Now I just need to wrap my head around what exactly is going on with this.  The tie part is what is confusing me.

Comment: `std::tie(b, a) = std::minmax(a, b);` this does something very different than you think. What you need is an `initializer_list` overload of `std::minmax`.

Comment: @user2797124 the std::tie creates a tuple of lvalue references to its arguments, meaning the assignment operator from a tuple to this tuple actually modifies the variables passed as arguments.

Comment: @robson3.14 fixed, however i'm pretty confused. Please explain the difference in more details :)

Comment: @SirDarius The two argument version probably thinks that `a` and `b` are iterators delimiting a range of values...Wait, I think that doesn't even happen and the non-braces version [should have worked, too](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax).

Comment: @ChristianRau I don't think that's the problem, if a = 6 and b = 5, std::minmax(a,b) effectively returns a pair<int,int> with values (5, 6).

Comment: @SirDarius I know, that's what I've written in the comment, too.

Comment: @ChristianRau sorry didn't see the second part of the comment, I'm going to promote this to a standalone question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912199/overloads-of-stdminmax-and-stdtie

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return tuples like that.

In C++, the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) will throw out the stuff on the left. In your particular case, the "tuple" `(a,b,c)` is actually equal to just `c`. A more concrete example:

```
if (b == 0) {
    return (a, 1, 0);
}
```

is actually the same as

```
if (b == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

To return multiple things at once, you'll have to use structs or classes.