# Overloads of std::minmax() and std::tie

Tags: c++, c++11

The [std::minmax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) function introduced in C++11 is supposed to return a pair of respectively the lowest and the greatest of the given values.

In this example:

```
int a = 6, b = 5;
auto p = std::minmax(a, b);
std::cout << "p.first = " << p.first << std::endl;
std::cout << "p.second = " << p.second << std::endl;
```

This works as advertised and prints

> p.first = 5
>   p.second = 6

Now I would like to effectively modify `a` and `b` to force b to be lower than a, as if running this code:

```
if (b > a)
    std::swap(a, b);
```

So I have written this:

```
int a = 5, b = 6;
std::tie(b, a) = std::minmax(a, b);
std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
```

However, this prints:

> a = 5
>   b = 5

Using the initializer_list overload instead, like this:

```
std::tie(b, a) = std::minmax({a, b});
```

causes the expected result to be printed:

> a = 6
>   b = 5

The compiler is GCC 4.7.1 (also tested with GCC 4.8.1 on Linux and Windows with Mingw-w64).
I have created an SSCCE at http://ideone.com/fA0qw5.

Why is the two-arguments overload not doing what it is supposed to do when using `std::tie` ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that `std::minmax` returns *references* for the 2-argument version. That way, as soon as `b` in the `std::tie(b, a)` is assigned, the change is reflected in the `b` part of the returned `std::pair`, giving it the value of `5` - which in turn is assigned to the `a` in `std::tie(b, a)`, yielding `(5, 5)` as the result.